# Theorem of Shelah about the existence of an inaccessible cardinal

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, forcing

There is a theorem of Shelah, stated in the following way:

If all $\Sigma_3^1$ sets of reals are measurable, then $\aleph_1$ is an inaccessible cardinal in $L$.

In some textbooks (for example Schindler, 2014: Set Theory, Exploring Independence and Truth) the theorem is stated slightly different. Instead of inaccessible cardinal in $L$, they say $\aleph_1^V$ is then inaccessible to the reals.

Can someone explain me why this is an equivalent way to state the theorem?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements are not equivalent. More precisely, $\omega_1$ being inaccessible to the reals is a strictly stronger statement then $\omega_1$ being inaccessible in $L$.

If $\omega_1$ is not inaccessible in $L$, let $\omega_1 = (\alpha^+)^L$ where $\alpha$ is a cardinal in $L$. Then $\alpha$ is countable in $V$ and therefore there exists a real $x \subset \omega$ coding a well order of length $\alpha$ on $\omega$, hence $\omega_1^{L[x]} = \omega_1$.

On the other hand, if $V = L[0^\sharp]$ then $\omega_1$ is inaccessible in $L$.